# Creating SQL to join 2 DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a requirement for joining the 2 DE based on the below condition

> Where Billed_Item_Status_DT =  3 days prior And Sales_Brand_CD = '520'

I've created the query but still not sure I'm right for 3 days prior condition. Can someone explain to me what actually 3 days prior mean?

Below is my SQL query.

```
SELECT

m.EMAIL_ADDR,
m.FIRST_NM,
m.BE_NAM,
m.CITY,
m.CONTACT_NAME_NBR_ID,
m.CORP_GROUP_ID,
m.CPERS_FULL_NM,
m.CUST_PARTY_EFF_DT,
m.CUST_SRGT_ID,
m.FIRST_BILD_ORD_DT,
m.IH_LEGACY,
m.SALES_BRAND_BSNSS_ID,
m.SALES_BRAND_CD,
m.SIC_CD,
m.STATE,
m.INTERNAL_EMAIL_USE,
m.LAST_BILD_ORD_DT,
m.LAST_NM,
m.LAST_UPDT_DT,
m.ONED_CUST,
m.PARTY_SRGT_ID,

p.BILLED_ITEM_STATUS_DT,
p.BOOKED_ITEM_STATUS_DT,
p.DISCOUNT_AMT,
p.EMAIL_ADD,
p.EXTRA_CHARGES_AMT,
p.LOB_CD,
p.LOB_CD_DSCR,
p.MINOR_MKT_CD,
p.MINOR_MKT_CD_DSCR,
p.ORDER_SOURCE,
p.PROD_AMT,
p.PROD_ID,
p.PROD_ID_DESC,
p.PROD_MKT_FAM,
p.PRODUCT_LINE,
p.PRODUCT_TITLE,
p.REQUEST_DETAIL_LINE_ID,
p.REQUEST_ID,
p.REV,
p.SHIPPING_COST,
p.SHIPPING_WAIVE_AMT,
p.SIC_CD_SHRT

FROM

ent.[1D Master Contacts Weekly] m LEFT JOIN ent.[RT_Customer_Purchase_Date_Table] p ON m.EMAIL_ADDR = p.EMAIL_ADD

WHERE p.BILLED_ITEM_STATUS_DT >=DATEADD(Day,datediff(day, 0,getdate()),-3)
AND
p.Sales_Brand_CD = '520'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "equals 3 days prior" means "exactly 3 days ago", then I'd write it like this:

```sql
SELECT
  m.EMAIL_ADDR
, m.FIRST_NM
, m.BE_NAM
, m.CITY
, m.CONTACT_NAME_NBR_ID
, m.CORP_GROUP_ID
, m.CPERS_FULL_NM
, m.CUST_PARTY_EFF_DT
, m.CUST_SRGT_ID
, m.FIRST_BILD_ORD_DT
, m.IH_LEGACY
, m.SALES_BRAND_BSNSS_ID
, m.SALES_BRAND_CD
, m.SIC_CD
, m.STATE
, m.INTERNAL_EMAIL_USE
, m.LAST_BILD_ORD_DT
, m.LAST_NM
, m.LAST_UPDT_DT
, m.ONED_CUST
, m.PARTY_SRGT_ID
, p.BILLED_ITEM_STATUS_DT
, p.BOOKED_ITEM_STATUS_DT
, p.DISCOUNT_AMT
, p.EMAIL_ADD
, p.EXTRA_CHARGES_AMT
, p.LOB_CD
, p.LOB_CD_DSCR
, p.MINOR_MKT_CD
, p.MINOR_MKT_CD_DSCR
, p.ORDER_SOURCE
, p.PROD_AMT
, p.PROD_ID
, p.PROD_ID_DESC
, p.PROD_MKT_FAM
, p.PRODUCT_LINE
, p.PRODUCT_TITLE
, p.REQUEST_DETAIL_LINE_ID
, p.REQUEST_ID
, p.REV
, p.SHIPPING_COST
, p.SHIPPING_WAIVE_AMT
, p.SIC_CD_SHRT
FROM ent.[1D Master Contacts Weekly] m 
LEFT JOIN ent.[RT_Customer_Purchase_Date_Table] p ON m.EMAIL_ADDR = p.EMAIL_ADD
WHERE p.BILLED_ITEM_STATUS_DT >= convert(date, getDate()-3) 
and p.BILLED_ITEM_STATUS_DT < convert(date, getDate()-2) 
AND p.Sales_Brand_CD = '520'
```

The `convert` to `date` strips the time portion from the datetime resulting from `getDate()`. The `-3` and `-2` just subtract days (it's the default interval).

Comment: Thanks, Adam for helping in this. Just a quick question. I didn't understand the part why we are using and p.BILLED_ITEM_STATUS_DT < convert(date, getDate()-2) ? When The 1st part is already subtracting 3 days.

Comment: My assumption is BILLED_ITEM_STATUS_DT is a Date data type (datetime in SFMC) that includes the time.  The ranged conditions handle the time portions, effectively making the criteria "any time of day, 3 days ago".

Comment: Correct Adam, It's an Date data type and it's having time in it. Thank you so much for helping this out and also clearing my doubts :)